# SQL, how to get data to show previous 30 days

Tags: sql

First thread, I couldn't find working solutions on others threads.

I'm need to get data from the last 30 days (example 20/09/21 to 20/10/21)

Edit: here is the correct database/table words.
Also, I'm using grafana with sql to have a nice chart.

So far my code is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM power_station
where CURDATE(installed) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

I also tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM power_station
WHERE installed >= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate()) 
and   installed <= getdate()
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: What's wrong with that second attempt. Did you get an error? Wrong results?

Comment: Your second query should work, although you won't need the `<=getdate()` unless your rows are dated in the future. What was the problem with this?

Comment: Like the two commentators said, your second statement should work.

Alternative way: `my_date_column between getDate()-30 AND getDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

try this code (PG example)

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where my_date_column > ((now() - interval '1 month'))
```

if you need text to date conversion use this code

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where my_date_column::date > ((now() - interval '1 month'))
```

you are using MySQL?

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table
where my_date_column > (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I didn't know that there is some differences between SQL code and Mysql. 

Your solution worked fine for me !

Comment: The answer with standard SQL term should also work fine

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE MY_DATE_COLUMN BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())) AND CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE() )
```

Converting to **Date** format, so that **time** can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

CURRENT_DATE is a standard SQL term which can be used for calculations.
So this should do it:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE my_date_column > CURRENT_DATE - 1 MONTH
```

or in days:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE my_date_column > CURRENT_DATE - 30 DAYS
```